# Issue with django rest framework when creating new objects

Tags: javascript, python, django, rest, django-rest-framework

I am trying to use django rest framework to create instances of a Bookmark model for different types of content, for example Book.

The code:

models.py

```
class Bookmark(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    content_type = models.ForeignKey(ContentType)
    object_id = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    content_object = GenericForeignKey('content_type', 'object_id')
```

api.py

```
from django.contrib.contenttypes.models import ContentType
from rest_framework import viewsets, mixins, serializers, permissions
from .models import Bookmark


class BookmarkSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Bookmark
        fields = ('id', 'user', 'content_type', 'object_id')


class BookmarkViewSet(mixins.CreateModelMixin,
                           mixins.ListModelMixin,
                           mixins.RetrieveModelMixin,
                           mixins.UpdateModelMixin,
                           mixins.DestroyModelMixin,
                           viewsets.GenericViewSet):
    queryset = Bookmark.objects.all()
    serializer_class = BookmarkSerializer
    permission_classes = [permissions.IsAuthenticatedOrReadOnly]


    def perform_create(self, serializer):
        content_type = self.request.query_params.get('content_type')
        app, model = content_type.split(".")
        ct = ContentType.objects.get_by_natural_key(app, model)

        object_id = self.request.query_params.get('object_id')

        serializer.save(user=self.request.user, content_type=ct, object_id=object_id)


    def get_queryset(self):
        items = Bookmark.objects.filter(user=self.request.user)

        content_type = self.request.query_params.get('content_type', None)
        if content_type: 
            app, model = content_type.split(".")
            ct = ContentType.objects.get_by_natural_key(app, model)
            items = items.filter(content_type=ct)

        object_id = self.request.query_params.get('object_id', None)
        if object_id:
            items = items.filter(object_id=object_id)

        return items
```

get_queryset part is fine. But perform_create fails when I try to create a new Bookmark:

```
var item = new Bookmark({'content_type': 'books.book', 'object_id': self.book_id});
item.save();
```

The response:

```
{"user":["This field is required."],"content_type":["Incorrect type. Expected pk value, received unicode."]}
```

It is not clear to me how I am supposed to do this. I would appreciate any feedback.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both previous answers pointed me in the right direction. In the end, the solution was not to override perform_create, but create function:

```
def create(self, request, *args, **kwargs):

    content_type = request.data['content_type']
    if content_type:
        app, model = content_type.split(".")
        ct = ContentType.objects.get_by_natural_key(app, model)

    request.data['user'] = request.user.id
    request.data['content_type'] = ct.id
    #object_id already passed as id in request.data
```

A further explanation can be read here:
https://github.com/encode/django-rest-framework/issues/3470

Answer (score 0):

You should post your model definition as well, but the error you are getting is saying that you also need to pass a `user` argument to `Bookmark` and that you should be passing a pk value (aka an integer that is the id of the object you're pointing to) for `content_type`.

Answer (score 0):

I can't say anything about the error message concerning the user, but here is my 2 cents about the second one.

You do not simply give a path to your model as a string to the `content_type` key.

[Apparently](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/contrib/contenttypes/#the-contenttypemanager)
, you have to use the `get_for_model` method which is passed as parameter a model (The model 'Book', not an instance of it), and returns an object of type `ContentType`. This object's `id` is what you should pass as a value.